# Finding the height of the building using Trigonometric Ratio.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, triangles

**Question:**
At a certain point in a large, level park, the angle of elevation to the top of an office building is ${30}^{\circ}$.
If you move ${400}ft$ closer to the building, the angle of elevation is ${45}^{\circ}$.
To the nearest ${10}ft$. how tall is the building?

**My Initial Calculation :**

For ${30}^{\circ}$ Triangle:
$$
\begin{array}{1}
=>\tan 30^{\circ}=\frac{h}{x+400}\\[0.1in]
=>h=0.577(x+400)\\[0.1in]
=>h=0.577x+230.8\\[0.1in]
\end{array}
$$

For ${45}^{\circ}$ Triangle:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
=>\tan 45^{\circ} = \frac{h}{x-400}\\[0.1in]
=>\tan 45^{\circ} = \frac{0.577(x+400)}{x-400}\\[0.1in]
=>\tan 45^{\circ} = \frac{0.577x+230.8}{x-400}\\[0.1in]
=>x-400=0.577x+230.8\\[0.1in]
=>x-0.577x=230.8+400\\[0.1in]
=>0.423x=630.8\\[0.1in]
=>x=\frac{630.8}{0.423}\\[0.1in]
=>x=1491.25\\[0.1in]
\end{array}
$$

How tall is Building:
$$
\begin{array}{1}
=>\tan 30^{\circ}=\frac{h}{x+400}\\[0.1in]
=>\tan 30^{\circ}=\frac{h}{1491.25+400}\\[0.1in]
=>h=1091.91ft\\
\end{array}
$$

The answer in the book is ${550ft}$, What wrong did I do in my calculation?

### **New Calculation :**

For ${30}^{\circ}$ Triangle:
$$
\begin{array}{1}
=>\tan 30^{\circ}=\frac{h}{x+400}\\[0.1in]
=>h=0.577(x+400)\\[0.1in]
=>h=0.577x+230.8\\[0.1in]
\end{array}
$$

For ${45}^{\circ}$ Triangle:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
=>\tan 45^{\circ} = \frac{h}{x}\\[0.1in]
=>\tan 45^{\circ} = \frac{0.577(x+400)}{x}\because h=0.577(x+400)\\[0.1in]
=>\tan 45^{\circ} = \frac{0.577x+230.8}{x}\\[0.1in]
=>x=0.577x+230.8\\[0.1in]
=>x-0.577x=230.8\\[0.1in]
=>0.423x=230.8\\[0.1in]
=>x=\frac{230.8}{0.423}\\[0.1in]
=>x=545.63\\[0.1in]
\end{array}
$$

How tall is Building:
$$
\begin{array}{1}
=>\tan 30^{\circ}=\frac{h}{x+400}\\[0.1in]
=>\tan 30^{\circ}=\frac{h}{545.63+400}\because x=545.63\\[0.1in]
=>h=545.95ft\\
\text{Rounded to the nearest 10}ft\\
=>h=550ft
\end{array}
$$

Comment: The error is that the difference between $x+400$ and $x-400$ is $800$ feet. If you denote the shorter distance by $x$, then the longer one is $x+400$. If you choose to denote the longer distance by $x$, then the shorter one is $x-400$. You absolutely should not use $x+400$ and $x-400$ both.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you, now the answer is aligned with the book.

Comment: Great! If so inclined, you can post the new calculation as an answer. That is ok, whenever it happens that an asker sorts out their problem, with or without help from hints/comments.

Comment: When you make a Diagram , you might see that more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pictorial View , with 3 variations , all will give the Same Solution :**

[image: 333]

In **Blue Case** , we have :
$\tan{30}=h/(x+400)$
$\tan{45}=h/(x)$
where $x$ is the Base length of the Smaller triangle.

In **Green Case** , we have :
$\tan{30}=h/(y)$
$\tan{45}=h/(y-400)$
where $y$ is the Base length of the Larger triangle.

In **Purple Case** , we have :
$\tan{30}=h/(z+200)$
$\tan{45}=h/(z-200)$
where $z$ is the Mid-Point of the Line Segment between the Bases of the 2 triangles.

**All variations will give the Same Equivalent Solution.**

**Where OP went wrong :**

What OP did was mostly Correct in trigonometric terms.

Where OP went wrong is : Mixing the Bases.
Like the **Purple Case** , OP took $x+400$ & $x-400$ , which is not the Criteria given & that will give wrong ( Double ! ) height.
Height will be scaled up & that will not match the text book.